# Add class to header on slider change

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

I am trying to be able to change my header background dynamically depending on which slide comes up. Each slide is pulling in a post from a cms, each of those posts have an option to add a background image or not. The ones with a background image have a div class of "intro-bg" ones that don't do not have that class. Essentially I want my header to be transparent when the ones with a background image are active slides, and then go back to normal with slides that do not have that class are active. Right now the code below makes the first part happen, but not the second part. The header background does not change after the next slide. I hope this all makes sense, below is my code I am not sure what is going wrong here. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
 $('.fade-carousel').on('init', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
     if ($('.slick-active .slide-container div').hasClass('intro-bg')) {
         $('#header').addClass('transparent-header')
     } else {
         $('#header').removeClass('transparent-header');
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'init' event will execute only once. In addition to what you are currently doing, you need to execute the same logic each time the slide is changed (only for the new slide). For example:

```
 $('.fade-carousel').on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
     if ($('.slide-container:eq('+nextSlide+') > div').hasClass('intro-bg')) {
         $('#header').addClass('transparent-header')
     } else {
         $('#header').removeClass('transparent-header');
     }
 });
```

Comment: Oh goodness, I tried something similar before the one I posted, but I was off a bit. Thank you for the clarification. I really appreciate it!

Comment: Ok last question if i can! It does work on slide transition, but what if one of the content creators places a slide without the "intro-bg" class in it. I notice that it loads with the transparent-header class added to the header. How can I fix that?

Comment: @AaronS If you include both `init` and `beforeChange` you should be fine. Alternatively you can force `beforeChange`: `$('.fade-carousel').trigger('beforeChange', [this, 0, 0]);` in `document.ready`.

Comment: I included init,  Am I adding it incorrectly?

`  $('.fade-carousel').on('init', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
    if ($('.slide-container:eq('+nextSlide+') > div').hasClass('intro-bg')){
      $('#header').addClass('transparent-header')
    }
    $('.fade-carousel').on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
        if ($('.slide-container:eq('+nextSlide+') > div').hasClass('intro-bg')) {
            $('#header').addClass('transparent-header')
        }
    else {
      $('#header').removeClass('transparent-header');
    }

});
});`

Comment: @AaronS That code is incorrect. Use the one in your question.

Comment: I actually just resolved it. Works perfectly!!! Thank you very much! Sorry for the back n forth.